# Angular.js - directive is called but used nowhere

Tags: angularjs, program-entry-point, directive

Following code is working although I didn't find authDemoApplication somewhere outside this file, not in *.js, nor in .html files.

```
angular.module('angular-auth-demo', ['http-auth-interceptor','content-mocks'])
  .directive('authDemoApplication', function() {
  });
```

So, how is this directive working and where to read about this method of calling?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't find anything like '<div class="demoApplication"></div>' in a .html file? There must be an element that has that class.

Comment: Yes, I looked again and didn't find it.

Comment: Did you look for 'auth-demo-application'?

Comment: Yeah! It was there: <body ng-app="angular-auth-demo" class="auth-demo-application waiting-for-angular"> Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directives are named in camelCase but referenced using hyphen-delimited names. Did you search for `<div auth-demo-application>` type syntax?

Comment: Indeed, it was there: <body ng-app="angular-auth-demo" class="auth-demo-application waiting-for-angular">